# Regarding JPA persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I am using hibernate JPA on tomcat. I created a connection pool on tomcat and it works fine independently. Now for my JPA to use this connection pool ; I created persistence.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="kids" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/kids</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It is giving me following exception:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should set the namespace attribute and the schema location for the persistence node:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
         version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="kids" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/kids</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: thanks it works fine. I thought all this xmlns etc attributes are optional.